# How to use apply DataFrame method with PyTorch library

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch

There are many useful methods in DataFrame that you would like to use when works with PyTorch library. Ir order to speedup the working with DataFrame.apply(for columns) method I decided to use PyTorch library.
My first impression that I cannot use this library for my task - PyTorch works with data as with usual numpy array.It means that I cannot speedup 'apply' method using PyTorch. I quess that it is true and for other nice DataFrame features. If I'm wrong please explain me how I could solve my problem...

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'apply' methond for PyTorch as far as I know. You can read these discussions for reference:

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/fast-way-to-use-map-in-pytorch/70814/13
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/map-function-in-pytorch/16539

In most cases, you want your operations to be as vectorized as possible and apply/map might be hard or impossible to vectorize naively.